# How to get decimal values from APPROX_QUANTILES function in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using this function to get the 80th percentile value of O2D in bigquery

```
APPROX_QUANTILES(O2D,100)[offset(80)] as O2D_P80
```

I would like my query to return 1 decimal point but the function is rounding off the value by default.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean "return 1 decimal point"?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: For example: the function above would return O2D as 40 minutes, I would like it to return 39.8 minutes.
The function is rounding the value of O2D by default, I do not want it to. I need an answer with one decimal value.

Comment: Try converting to a float or numeric when you make the call.